# Evaluated Powers of Bases if gcd of 3 bases is 1 without using tons of for loops

Tags: matlab, greatest-common-divisor

I'm trying to make a program that will evaluate the gcd of 3 numbers (the bases), and if the GCD of `base1` and `base2`, `base2` and `base3`, and `base3` and `base1` are all equal to one, then evaulate the bases to exponents in a range. Basically, what I need to do is figure out if their GCD's are equal to one, then calculate the numbers to powers. Here's what it would look like:

```
bases = 150
powers = 150
base1 = all numbers 1-bases
base2 = all numbers 1-bases
base3 = all numbers 1-bases
if the GCD of all combinations = 1
    do base1^all numbers 3-powers
    do base2^all numbers 3-powers
    do base2^all numbers 3-powers
    then store all of those in an array
```

Now, I've tried using the dreaded `for` loops, but it is very slow and I'm not considering it a solution. It only works quickly if bases and powers are 10 or below. How can I do this without using `for` loops? Or, if I have to use a `for` loop, how can I reduce the number that is used? Could I computate what numbers together's 3 GCD combinations equal 1? The `for` loop that I've tried is below:

```
for i = 1:numbers
    for j = 1:numbers
        for k = 1:numbers
            if gcd(i,j) == 1 && gcd(i,k) == 1 && gcd(k,j) == 1
                for a = 3:powers
                    for b = 3:powers
                        for c = 3: powers
                            x = i^a
                            y = j^b
                            z = k^c
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem can be solved in a vecctorized manner as follows

```
%Generate all possible triplets.
[x1,x2,x3]=ndgrid(1:3,1:3,1:3);
v=[x1(:) x2(:) x3(:)];
```

Now define an anonymous function.

```
gcd3_test=@(a,b,c)(gcd(a,b)==1 & gcd(b,c)==1 & gcd(a,c)==1)
gcdTest=gcd3_test(v(:,1),v(:,2),v(:,3));
v=v(gcdTest,:);
```

Similarly generate the triplets for all your powers.

```
[x1,x2,x3]=ndgrid(3:10,3:10,3:10);
p=[x1(:) x2(:) x3(:)];
```

Then I guess you will have to use the for loop (but only one) as:

Important: I assume if you run the `for` loop for powers `3:150`, and you need to store all `x,y,z` then you will need lots of memory (35034 GB, even with single precision). You are not doing that in your code.

So do not try the following for loop.

```
%DO NOT RUN
for i=1:size(v,1)
    vReplicated=repmat(v(i,:),size(p,1),1);
    v_RaisedTo_P{i}=vReplicated.^p;
end
```

Note: Observe that you don't care about the order when conducting your GCD test (i.e. your `if` condition. So I think you can filter out lot of triplets, but this will affect your power calculation.

```
allTriplets=sort(allTriplets,2);
allTriplets=unique(allTriplets,'rows'); %27 triplets reduce to 10
```

Comment: So if I shouldn't run that last `for` loop, what should I do instead?

Comment: @hichris123 You possibly cannot store all `a,b and c`. Something is weird in your code, you are overwriting `a,b and c` (why?). If you want to do that just remove the `cell array` from the answer. Then its easy. If you want to store all `a,b and c`, you will need `35034 GB`. I checked.

Comment: You can run for small numbers indeed, say 10. See if you get desired results and compare then with your `for loop` solution.

Comment: @hichris123 sorry, I meant you are overwriting `x,y and z`

Comment: I edited my question since I thought you were refering to the powers. My fault.

Comment: It's giving me this error, `Error using  .^ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in bignum2 (line 14)
    v_RaisedTo_P{i}=vReplicated.^p;`.

Comment: Still, your edit doesn't answer my question. My question is, if you are not storing all `x,y and z`, then what is the point of running such a big loop. If you want it that way, then I will edit my code and then you can run it for an arbitrarily large number as long as `(number^3)*3*4/1024^3` is a number which can fit into memory. Approximately number=600 for a `4 GB` RAM computer.

Comment: I would be storing it, but just didn't want to put it in that `for` loop to make it more confusing.

Comment: Ok. Did this solve your entire problem, except storing?

Answer (score 0):

The code suggests you already have the gcd for two integers implemented or you use the build in? gcd(a,b,c) is equal to gcd(a,gcd(b,c))

```
gcd3=@(a,b,c)(gcd(a,gcd(b,c)))
```

Comment: I do, but I'm not sure how to do this without using that many for loops.

Comment: You are right, this does not really help. First time reading, I got your question wrong. Updated answer will follow.

Comment: Very confusing problem, don't have a solution.